# Symbol Search: How to exclude html/js docs files or only include `.py` modules?

Tags: python, pycharm, full-text-search

Generating documentation for my (Python) projects creates a lot of `.html` and `.js` files that pollute PyCharm's "Symbol Search". How can I tell the system to exclude `*.html` and `.js` files, or exclude the `docs/` folder, or only **include** `.py` files.

[image: Symbol search results]

Answer (score 0):

Using [*Symbol Search*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/searching-everywhere.html) (shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) it is possible to apply [a costum scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html) to filter the results by clicking the drop down as shown in the screenshot. (The example project also has a `docs` directory with generated documentation.)

[image: first screenshot search symbol]

The *Search Symbol* dialogue doesn't allow you to set a costum scope, so first you'll have to set it by going to `File` `>` `Settings` `>` `Appearance & Behavior` `>` `Scopes` `>` `Add Scope` by clicking the `+` plus sign.

[image: screenshot settings scope]

> How can I tell the system to exclude `*.html` and `.js`

Here you have two options that can be combined, both are shown in the above screenshot, either:

1. Choose the files and directories (in your case the `docs` directory) and press the `Include` and `Exclude` buttons manually.
2. Or write a [Scope configuration control](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html#options) manually. (In your case it would be `!file[Your_project_name]:*js&&!file:*html`).

[image: second screenshot search symbol]

Finally if you now apply *Symbol Search* the results will be restricted to the defined scope.

**End note:** The default scope is *Project Files* which already restricts searches to the within the open project. When defining a costum scope you may need to exclude the venv and any other projects that may be open in the Project View.